# removing event listener in moodle

Tags: moodle, moodle-boost

I created a moodle block plugin which contains a form.

When a mobile user try to use the form, the resizing of the window due to popup of the keyboard closed the drawer block, I tried to investigate which event listener causes this and here is the code of the handler:

```
    define("core/utils", ["exports"], (function(_exports) {
    Object.defineProperty(_exports, "__esModule", {
        value: !0
    }),
    _exports.throttle = _exports.debounce = void 0;
    _exports.throttle = (func,wait)=>{
        let onCooldown = !1
          , runAgain = null;
        const run = function() {
            for (var _len = arguments.length, args = new Array(_len), _key = 0; _key < _len; _key++)
                args[_key] = arguments[_key];
            runAgain = null !== runAgain,
            onCooldown || (func.apply(this, args),
            onCooldown = !0,
            setTimeout((()=>{
                const recurse = runAgain;
                onCooldown = !1,
                runAgain = null,
                recurse && run(args)
            }
            ), wait))
        };
        return run
    }
    ;
    _exports.debounce = (func,wait)=>{
        let timeout = null;
        return function() { // THIS IS THE HANDLER.
            for (var _len2 = arguments.length, args = new Array(_len2), _key2 = 0; _key2 < _len2; _key2++)
                args[_key2] = arguments[_key2];
            clearTimeout(timeout),
            timeout = setTimeout((()=>{
                func.apply(this, args)
            }
            ), wait)
        }
    }
}
));
```

I don't know how to add a code using $this->page->requires->js_init_code($code); to stop this event

Note that I'm using moove (boost child) theme.